# Book about a girl with telekinetic powers who is accused of killing her grandmother by pushing her down the stairs

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, telekinesis

This book came from my grandmother's basement, so it's probably from the 1970s or so, but that's just a guess.

This girl has strange eyes, and can move things things with her mind. She was accused of killing her grandmother by pushing her down the stairs.

The power came from a drug that her mother took, and there are 4 others like her. One of them was named Eric.

When they work together, they are able to make a Mr. P's groceries explode or something like that?

And a Mr. C is stalking her or something.

Sorry if there's not much to go on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the one you are looking for, and I haven't read it in 20 years... But I THINK you are talking about '[The Girl with the Silver Eyes.](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/198719.The_Girl_with_the_Silver_Eyes)'

Details that I remember:

- Her powers are due to a painkiller her mother took during childbirth/pregnancy -- at one point she finds a photo of her mother and a few others who were all part of the trial of the drug.  (At the time, it made me think of [Thalidomide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thalidomide), and may well have been based on it.)
- There were a number of others, and she's able to track them down, and arrange some kind of sleep-over for the group of them to meet.
- She is telekinetic, not to mention being able to communicate with a least an animal or two.  One of the other kids (who she meets in a park with his dog, I think) can also communicate, with his dog, as I recall.  I THINK they were able to communicate with each other, as well.
- A Mr. Cooper moves into her complex and takes way too much of an interest in her; possibly looking for her and those like her -- it's been too long to remember for sure.
- She comes to live with her mother, after he grandmother dies, and there is some suspicion about her being involved with it.
- I believe it was first out in 1980.

[Here's another review.](http://www.everyday-reading.com/2009/11/girl-with-silver-eyes-by-willo-davis.html), and [a page with a bunch of reviews](http://www.bookiverse.com/books/the-girl-with-the-silver-eyes/), a lot of which summarize the story.

As I recall, it ended with a hopeful sequel hook; basically Mr. Cooper talking about the kids attending a school for others like themselves. Unfortunately, the author, Willo Davis Roberts, died in 2004 of congestive heart failure, so there is no official sequel.

---

**[Edit]**
With regard to "*When they work together, they are able to make a Mr. P's groceries explode or something like that?*", I believe this cover is a reference to exactly that:

[image: Cover for The Girl with the Silver Eyes]

Comment: Wow hahaha when I saw the question title I was like "hmmm, I wonder if...". Nice to see I'm not the only person to have read this book.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely "The Girl With the Silver Eyes." I have the book, and I just reread it a few weeks ago.

The girl's name is Katie, and her eyes are, as the title notes, silver. The powers come from a painkiller drug that her mother used along with three other women who got pregnant because of it, who are the other children with silver eyes. The drugs apparently genetically modified the children so that they would have those powers. Katie is telekinetic and can communicate with humans, cats, and possibly dogs with her mind.

Mr.C, or Mr. Cooper, is not her stalker, but rather a guy who works for the Institute of Paranormal Powers and wants to make sure that Katie is truly a person with paranormal powers and not a charlatan (the definition is in the book).

She was accused of killing her grandmother by the Armbrusters, but the police never came for her because of that. She thought they did, though, so she ran away. She already knows Dale at this point, and then she communicates with Eric with her mind, assisted by Dale, and they meet at a fountain. They three go to Katie's home and find that Kerri is there with her parents, as someone who knew about the peculiarity of all four kids had called a meeting or something of the sort (it was never revealed how the parents came together then). The kids, now with a Kerri that clandestinely slipped away "for her handkerchief," walk into the meeting and things are explained.

Any memory recall? Do you remember now?

Comment: OP has already accepted an answer to this effect, so this reads more like a comment.

Comment: Then why not have only one answer for each question? Anyway, I like pouring out the thoughts in my head. They really need to stop distracting me. I was also letting people know that she was never officially accused of killing her grandma. If you have a problem with this answer.......

Comment: Multiple answers are not a problem. *Redundant* answers are. I am expressing my problem with your answers by flagging and commenting on them. This is how the users of the site seek to improve its content. I can only speak for myself, but I am attempting to enforce the conventions of the site as I understand them.

Comment: I think it added some useful new information. Sometimes, it is tricky when to know to add your own answer, or to fix someone else's.

Comment: Thank you, Fuzzy Boots. Glad to know that my answer helped you in a way that added to you amount of information. And thanks for the support.